# How to partially parse JSON using Go partly without key?

Tags: json, go, struct

I have this JSON

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "sources": {
        "source1": {
            "type": "number",
            "url": "<path>",
            "min": 0,
            "max": 10
        },
        "source2": {
            "type": "number",
            "url": "<path>",
            "min": 1,
            "max": 15
        },
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "data1",
            "type": "point"
        },
        {
            "id": "data2",
            "type": "line"
        },
    ]
}
```

and I need to extract in one Object the sources, and in the others the data. As for the data, it is quite easy to put it with json.Unmarshal() into a struct, because all properties can be read out from the JSON file with the json-tags. But the problem with the sources is, that I need to get the name "source1" and "source2". How can I extract that, without having a json tag that fits?

My attempt was this:

```
type Sources struct {
    Source map[string]Source `json:"sources"`
}

type Source struct {
    Type   string `json:"type"`
    Url string `json:"url"`
    Min int      `json:"min"`
    Max int      `json:"max"`
}
```

I would like to have for the Source also the Name attribute, but I do not know how I could map it.

Comment: This should work. The keys in the map `Sources.Source` will contain the JSON keys `source1` and `source2`. What have you tried?

Comment: my result object where I Unmarshal it, looks like this: {map[source1:{[myurl] 0 10} source2:{[myurl] 1 15}]}. But how can I access the source1 and source2 values?

Comment: Using a for-loop: `for k,v:=range sources.Source { }`